# Wrong presence shown for unsbscribe user in ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I have below roster list of `admin`:

```
Jabber ID                       Subscription    Pending 
user1@manish-lenovo-g510        to              in
```

if `user1` is not logged in

```
    connection.addHandler(Gab.on_presence, null, "presence");
```

shows `subscribe` but if `user1` log in the above handler show `online` presence and i am able to do chat. So if `user1` is logged in i am not able to know that he is subscribed or not as it show `online`. SO how can i avoid chat without subscription ?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question ? It is not obvious why you think the subscription are incorrect. Moreover, chatting and subscription are two separate things in XMPP. Subscription are only for presence and does nothing related to chat.